# IE WebDriver Selenium in Use with Active Directory Login

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

When attempting to navigate to a web page using the Selenium WebDriver for IE, I run into the issue of not being able to login to the site. The login is a windows security Active Directory login that appears in a popup like below. Has anyone had any luck with getting into this login?

[image]

Comment: Did you try 'pre-loading' the URL, `http://username:password@url.com'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK not with webdriver anyway. Your best chance is to look for a proxy that is capable of handling kerberos, NTLM or whatever you have there.

Anyway, with firefox i had some luck with user:pass@yoursite.com mechanizm, but I don't remember what authentication scheme was used in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier, with Firefox its possible by creating a profile.
Other than that HtmlUnitDriver supports active directory login to be used for authentication.