# How to handle WIndows Active Directory Authentication pop using selenium webdriver in IE browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

Please visit to this link to see image: https://blogs.ncl.ac.uk/isg/files/2012/05/popup.png

Note: I want to enter credentials and click ok button. AS I have tried normal sendKeys functions but didn't worked well. PLease guide me through this.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226211/ie-webdriver-selenium-in-use-with-active-directory-login

Comment: Yes but they didn't mention any solution.

Comment: Can u try this http://seleniumwebdrivertrainings.com/by-using-selenium-webdriver-how-to-handle-login-pop-up-window/ . But it is only for Firefox and chrome browers

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try giving your URL in the following format :

```
http://username:password@the-site.com
```

replace username password and the-site with your desired credentials and the site at test

Comment: Tried but it's just opening the browser.

Comment: To disable this behavior in Internet Explorer, create iexplore.exe DWORD values in one of the following registry key and set their value data to 0.
For all users of the program, set the value in the following registry key:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE**

Answer (score 0):

How to Handle Windows Pop-up Using AutoIt and Selenium Automation Testing
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/autoit-tutorial-to-download-write-autoit-script/
will certainly help you out!